# Round Image View getting with KingFisher (iOS - Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, kingfisher

### Scenario:

I have a @IBOutlet weak var posterImageView: UIImageView! that I'm showing on my tableView using Kingfisher (I have to use it). The image comes from an API. So, it's all right, the image is showing ok, but I want to show this image as a circle. I did without this kingfisher and it worked, using:

```
posterImageView.layer.cornedRadius = posterImageView.frame.size.width/2
posterImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

But with kingfisher I'm doing this:

```
let imgStg: String = self.movies[indexPath.row].poster!
let imgURL: URL? = URL(string: imgStg)
let imgSrc = ImageResource(downloadURL: imgURL!, cacheKey: imgStg)

cell.posterImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgSrc)
```

Inside this function:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

So, when I call posterImageView.layer.cornedRadius ... on my viewDidLoad(), xcode say that there is no such posterImageView on my TableViewController.

How can I custom my image view with this kingfisher call?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly I think you are supposed to enter the code to get the rounded image on your **cellForRowAtindexPath** method not viewDidLoad, so:

```
  let imgStg: String = self.movies[indexPath.row].poster!
    let imgURL: URL? = URL(string: imgStg)
    let imgSrc = ImageResource(downloadURL: imgURL!, cacheKey: imgStg)

    cell.posterImageView.layer.cornedRadius = posterImageView.frame.size.width/2
    cell.posterImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.posterImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgSrc)
```

Edit: Just remembered that KingFisher has support for rounded images:

```
let processor = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 20)
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil, options: [.processor(processor)])
```

Hope one of the two ways works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue, then I found this solution, so I want to share:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func download(url: String?, rounded: Bool = true) {
        guard let _url = url else {
            return
        }
        if rounded {
            let processor = ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: self.frame.size) |> RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: self.frame.size.width / 2)
            self.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: _url), placeholder: nil, options: [.processor(processor)])
        } else {
            self.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: _url))
        }
    }
}
```

The big secret here is this instruction:

```
ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: self.frame.size)
```